# Cloudera Spark-Avro Tutorial fails for a custom avro file

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying Spark with Avro for the first time. After digging thru the various forums, I was able to get the following example.

https://github.com/sryza/simplesparkavroapp

The example was very information and ran successfully for the User.avro that came with the tutorial. I tried to replace the user.avro to my custom Avro classand it failed. I registered the Avro class as instructed in the tutorial.  I'm getting the following exception (complete stacktrace). Could anybody advise what is going on?.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0.0:9 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Exception failure in TID 17 on host vllxbd621node07.scif.com: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to com.cloudera.sparkavro.User
        com.cloudera.sparkavro.SparkSpecificAvroReader$$anonfun$1.apply(SparkSpecificAvroReader.scala:43)
        com.cloudera.sparkavro.SparkSpecificAvroReader$$anonfun$1.apply(SparkSpecificAvroReader.scala:43)
        scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:717)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:717)
        org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1080)
        org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1080)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1033)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1017)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1015)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1015)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1207)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
15/03/23 13:36:05 INFO YarnClientClusterScheduler: Stage 0 was cancelled
15/03/23 13:36:05 INFO TaskSetManager: Loss was due to java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to com.cloudera.sparkavro.User [duplicate 18]
```